# Output SQL query results in particular format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query which gives number1, number2 from numbertable.

```
Select number1, number2 from numbertable where number2 in(1,2,3)
```

The results give:

```
number1 number2
1       1
2       2
```

But I want to get results in following format:

```
(1,1)
(2,2)
```

I tried using following code,But I'm missing something

```
Select @number1 = number1, @number2 = @number2 from numbertable
where number2 in(1,2,3)
```

Comment: I suggest you should format your data outside of the query. You get the raw data and let your view, service do the formatting job.

Comment: I agree with @richerlariviere. What happens when you want the data in another format? If the formatting logic is buried in your query you'd be forced to either re-factor to extract the formatting logic, parse the current format or write a separate query with a different output format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `SQL SERVER 2012+` you can use `CONCAT`

```
SELECT Concat('(', number1, ',', number2, ')') 
FROM   numbertable 
WHERE  number2 IN( 1, 2, 3 )
```

else you use `+` to concatenate the strings

```
SELECT '(' + Cast(number1 AS VARCHAR(10)) + ',' + Cast(number2 AS VARCHAR(10)) + ')' 
FROM   numbertable 
WHERE  number2 IN( 1, 2, 3 )
```

As a side note, Consider doing this in application side